The second law of thermodynamics and the uniqueness of heat flow?
From wiki:

A simple statement of the law is that heat always flows spontaneously from hotter to colder regions of matter (or 'downhill' in terms of the temperature gradient).

I have a question:
Isn't it true for all the gradients (gravitational, electrical, chemical, pressure, concentration etc.) in physics? Energy flows to close gradients in particular direction (to even out). Evergy gradients all act like that. I mean,

water spontaneously flows from high pressures to low pressures,
stones spontaneously fall from higher elevation to lower elevations,
electrons spontaneously flow from high potential to low potential (yeah, there is a convenction for the direction of the flow +-, but you know what I mean: gradient spontaneously close, just like the temperature gradient),
etc.


Why speak of "heat" only in "heat always flows spontaneously from hotter to colder".
Why don't we speak of "energy always flows spontaneously to close a corresponding gradient to spread out more", why talk only about "heat" like it's special when there are examples above.

Don't get me wrong, I know that "heat" is special. But I don't see how this formulation of the second law renders it special among other gradients and energy fluxes.
P.S. I guess, we rather need to speak of "thermal energy" and not of "heat" but the quote is the quote.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.


Isn't it true for all the gradients (gravitational, electrical,
chemical, pressure, concentration etc.) in physics? Energy flows to
close gradients in particular direction (to even out). Energy
gradients all act like that.

You are correct.
However, outside the realm of statistical mechanics, the calculation of the entropy change, if any, for any process will generally require that the change in entropy be expressed in terms of heat and temperature, and not the other physical phenomena you've mentioned and there associated gradients. Consider the following:
Heat always generates entropy for any finite temperature difference (any gradient) making it inherently irreversible. Only when the gradient approaches zero will heat approach being reversible.
On the other hand, your other examples may or may not generate entropy. For example, an object falling in a vacuum may generate no entropy. If the object (the system) happens to collide with an ideal spring (the surroundings) causing it to rebound, it can theoretically return to its original state with no change to either the system or surroundings. Unlike heat, the process can theoretically be made reversible regardless of the "steepness" of the gradient.
But when these other examples do generate entropy, it is most often the result of the dissipative effects of some form of friction. That results in, or is generally associated with, the cause and/or effect of heat.  While the study of mechanics, fluids and electromagnetism accounts for the dissipative effects as a loss of some form of mechanical energy or electrical energy, that is where they generally stop, with thermodynamics taking over. Thermodynamics then defines entropy change as a function of a reversible transfer of heat, $\delta Q_{rev}$ at a boundary temperature of $T$:
$$dS=\frac{\delta Q_{rev}}{T}$$
For a total entropy change of the system between two equilibrium states of:
$$\Delta S_{12}=\int_1^2\frac{\delta Q_{rev}}{T}$$
So the  @J.Murray statement "because we're talking about thermodynamics" really isn't too glib.
Hope this helps.

You say: any process will generally require that the change in entropy be expressed in terms of heat and temperature, and not the other physical phenomena, Generally? Do you say thar there are formulas for entropy generation in some non-temperature gradient which are not of the form Q/T? Can you give examples in your question? I’m not talking about S=klogW

And another question: so, do you think that “heat flows down gradient” in this particular statement has anything to do with entropy at all? It looks to me that it is not, so did it look to Clausius imho (see my answer)

As far as I know the only type of leakage of energy from any gradient (without making another gradient of other type) is Q. I wonder is there a formula for energy to sound dissipation? :)

@coobit 1. I said generally to leave open the possibility there may be some situations where a problem would lend itself more suited for the Boltzmann law, as I am not conversant in applying that law. 2. The gradient here means a temperature difference and yes that has all to do with entropy generation. The greater the difference the greater the entropy generated. 3. Yes there are energy formulas for sound.

@coobit You might find this article about sound (vibration energy) and entropy interesting. In particular the statement:
“The main idea is that, because under certain conditions, vibrational energy may be assimilated to heat, it becomes possible to apply Clausius definition of entropy and therefore to introduce a vibrational entropy as well as a vibrational temperature”. https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rspa.2016.0602#:~:text=The%20main%20idea%20is%20that,well%20as%20a%20vibrational%20temperature.

Would "because we're talking about thermodynamics" be too glib an answer?
Note also that water, stones, and electrons are not energy. There are gradients and corresponding "flows" in the scenarios you describe, but they all occur for different reasons (molecular collisions, gravity, and the electromagnetism, respectively). In that sense they are analogous, and the flow of heat does fit the analogy.
But there are a thousand and one ways to make a plausible sounding analogy which isn't actually true. What if I said that heat flows from high thermal energy density to low thermal energy density? That fits the template of the analogy, but is completely wrong, so it's rather important to include the correct assertion as part of the foundation of thermodynamics.

"Note also that water, stones, and electrons are not energy." True. But I could have used other terms like "kinetic energy of water "flows from P1 to P0", "gravitational energy of stones drop from h1 to h0" etc.

On the other point of view, I don't quite understand. Why is there a law for "heat flows," but not for "kinetic energy of water flows"? Heat is clearly unique in some way, but this formulation of the second law doesn't seem to highlight this uniqueness.

@coobit My point is that you can't do physics by analogy. Can you explain why heat does not flow along gradients in thermal energy density rather than gradients in temperature? As far as heat being unique, there is a law for the flow of energy in a fluid - or rather, there are the laws of fluid dynamics.

I'm not using analogies just for the sake of it. I really don't understand why other types of gradients seem to behave according to the second law, but the law doesn't mention them and only focuses on the heat flow.

"Would "because we're talking about thermodynamics" be too glib an answer?" I think it is perfect (+1). When we are studying EM we do talk about voltage gradients. When we are studying fluid flow we do talk about pressure gradients. So we don't only speak of heat gradients, we just do so when we are studying thermodynamics

@Dale, I meant a different thing. I know that people speak of gradients and their opening or closing in the corresponding disciplines, but... Why the 2nd law speaks of heat like it's something special "Look, it flows! It's flowing down temperature gradient! It's like unique, right? No one has seen anything flowing down a gradient. So let's call it THE LAW"... Strange logic by my standards. Ok, we can stress the flowing of heat down but why call it the law in thermodynamics? If so why there is no such law in electricity, or hydrodynamics?

@J.Murray, Now that Dale commented your answer to my question, I get your meaning. Yes, we speak of "heat flowing down the temperature gradient in thermodynamics" just because we try to undestand what heat does, thus the laws about heat and not about whales or fish. I got that. But my question is different: Why there are no corresponding formulations of the same "energy flow down the gradient" in other branches of physics, like, electricity, hydrodynamics, chemistry, gravity? Why no such statements are made into laws there?

@coobit Ohm's law? Fick's law? Newton's second law (for conservative forces)?? The second law of thermodynamics is indeed privileged because it is in some sense more fundamental than the others, but I remain mystified as to why you find it odd that the second law of thermodynamics is about thermodynamics.

@J.Murray, Yeahm I know of them. But the trick with the 2nd law is that it is linked to this enigma -- entropy. No other laws are linked to it, right? The greatness of the second law is in entropy. Now is the question: "Is the OP quote of the second law from wiki has ANYTHING to do with entropy or this form of the 2nd law is an idiocy?" Clearly, the flow and gradients are all over physics, but no entropy was ever discovered there, it was discovered in thermodynamcs only! Finally, I've been able to express myself. Thanks.

J. Murray,
I'll try to rephrase my question:
Is the wiki quote which says that "heat flows down" is essence of the 2nd law an idiocy since it has nothing to do with entropy which is the only true main point of the 2nd law? Should we edit the wiki article? Because the second law is mainly about entropy, but "flowing down a gradient" is a common concept in physics and has nothing to do with entropy?

@coobit I would recommend against calling things idiotic, especially while you're still early in your study of physics. The statement that heat spontaneously flows from high temperature to low temperature is very nearly the original phrasing of the Clausius form of the 2nd law of thermodynamics. You may not think that it has anything to do with entropy, but it can be shown to be equivalent to the other formulations of the law which reference entropy explicity. Consider approaching this subject (and physics in general) with a bit more humility.

@J.Murray I speak not of arrogance but of frustration. So many times poor wording sent me chasing my own tail, so to speak :) on the subject: you say that “heat flows down” could be shown to be equivalent to more formal statements of the law (with entropy and stuff) but how? If it is upto isomorphism the same as other such “laws” in electricity, gravity etc.? No entropy being mentioned there, right?

@coobit J. Murray The original Clausius' phrasing may not be decisive; we should use "2nd law" here to refer to the present-day meaning. Clausius started from the general principle which states what kind of processes cannot occur, namely transformation of heat into work without further change, and we regard this as the content of the 2nd law. However, Clausius then derived his theorem $\oint \frac{dQ}{T} = 0$ for reversible processes, and called that an expression of the 2nd law. See the paper by Xue and Guo https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7514258/pdf/entropy-21-00926.pdf

@JánLalinský 3 hours ago I posted my own answer with exact same paper, you didn't notice it. :) Thnaks for the comment, anyways!

@coobit Indeed I've noticed only after I posted that comment. I searched for the "original Clausius statement" and got to the same paper as you.

@JánLalinský You did the right thing, I could have never found the paper and without your link the issue would have remained a moot for me for eternity. :)

Just to add something to this discussion, I'd like to say that I've found other people who are also bothered by similar thoughts:

However, it is strange that the second law of thermodynamics is quite different from other laws, like Newton’s law of motion, Ohm’s law of electric conduction, and Fourier’s law of heat conduction, etc. There are differences such as;
(1) there are many different statements for the same law;
(2) it is only a qualitative description of a physical phenomenon, rather than a
quantitative relationship between different physical quantities; and
(3) some phenomena similar to the Clausius Statement exist in other
disciplines. For example, an object can never move from low to high
location in a gravity field without some other change, and electrical
charges can never move from low to high potential in an electrostatic
field without some other change.
However, none of them has been accepted as the statement of a certain law. With that in mind, we have reviewed Clausius’ mechanical theory of heat, published in the
nineteenth century [14,15], and indeed found that he himself only
called “Heat can never pass from a colder to a warmer body without
some other change, connected therewith, occurring at the same time” a
fundamental principle rather than the statement of the second law of
thermodynamics.

source: "What Is the Real Clausius Statement of the Second Law of Thermodynamics?"
another quote by the authors:

Considering the natural tendency that heat always passes from a warmer to a colder body for eliminating the temperature difference, Clausius presented a well-known proposition that “Heat can never pass from a colder to a warmer body without some other change, connected therewith, occurring at the same time”.


... this proposition had only been laid down as a fundamental principle by Clausius.


In spite of this, regrettably, ever since then, this fundamental principle was usually mistaken for the Clausius Statement of the second law, probably because of its well-understood empirical property.

So, it looks like, the authors agree that "heat flowing down gradient" is not a rendition of the 2nd law, and thus has little to do with entropy...

I’d like to address one of your comments, because I think it provides the best summary of your question:

I really don't understand why other types of gradients seem to behave according to the second law, but the law doesn't mention them and only focuses on the heat flow.

Note that the text you quote in your question states “A simple statement of the law” (emphasis added). This version focuses on spontaneity of heating. More generally, the Second Law says that total entropy tends to increase.
One example of this is heat flow down a temperature gradient. Explanation: Infinitesimal heat flow $q$ from (into) a small region at approximately constant temperature $T$ removes (adds) infinitesimal entropy $q/T$. From this we find that heat flow down a temperature gradient generates entropy (compare denominators of $T_1>T_2$ on the outcome), whereas heat flow up a temperature gradient—all else equal—destroys entropy. Thus, only the former is permitted. (You asked about the specific dependence on the gradient. The volumetric entropy generation rate for one-dimensional conductive heat flow in some region at temperature $T$ is $\sigma=\frac{k}{T^2}\left(\frac{dT}{dx}\right)^2$, with thermal conductivity $k$; see Balluffi, Allen, and Carter, Kinetics of Materials, for instance, for a derivation.)
But another example of this is minimization of energy potentials (e.g., enthalpy, the chemical potential, the gravitational potential energy) for nonisolated systems. Explanation: derived here. For example, the Gibbs free energy $G$ and thus the chemical potential $\mu$ are minimized for systems in thermal and mechanical contact with their surroundings. For an isothermal pressure gradient, therefore, a chemical potential shift $d\mu=v\,dP$ (molar volume $v$, pressure $P$) tends to eliminate the gradient. In this way, an infinitesimal volume shift $dV=-w/P$ is spontaneous if it increases the volume of the more-compressed system, with more details given in Callen, Section 2-7. This enforces a preferred direction for work $w$ done on a system in this context, analogous to the preferred direction for heating $q$.
So the resolution that best addresses your question is that directional heating spontaneity and energy minimization (in some cases, directional work spontaneity) both follow from the broad tendency of entropy maximization, although only the former is emphasized in the Wikipedia quote.

1st, I dont want to be a stickler for tiny details, and I cant be since i’m no master of physics, but Q/T is not defined for “temperature gradients” thus there is only one T in the formula and not two different.

2nd “about the Q/T renders the flow unidirectional…” i can in principle invent another term w/p (work over pressure) which just happens to be a state variable and which also has a sign when talking about pressure tanks equilibrations, right? Why then the 2nd law does not mentions formulas like W/p?

(1) I’m referring to the entropy that leaves one small region (at some temperature $T_1$) as it cools slightly and to the entropy of another small region (at temperature $T_2$) as it warms slightly. Since this is a point of interest, I’ll add a more general description of the entropy generation rate for heat flow down a temperature gradient.

(2) The Second Law does indeed predict this spontaneity of work done in pressure equalization, through minimization of the relevant energy potential. I’ll add this description.
